# Не получаю пакеты из приложения на Linux в VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Закинул в Docker приложение на Java.
Оно должно отправлять по сети на другой компьютер покеты по протоколу udp в режиме multicast по адресу 224.1.1.244 и порту 53000.
Наружу прокинул порты 5003 для фронта и 53000.
Контейнер запускаю через docker-compose:

```
services:    
  upload-srv:
    image: ${SERV_IMAGE_STEND}
    networks:
      - es-serv-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: es-serv-v01
    volumes:
      - /home/es-serv:/home/es-serv
    ports:
      - "5003:5003"
      - "53000.:53000."
...        
networks:
  es-serv-network:
```

Сам Docker запускается в OS Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) в VirtualBox. А на самом хосте установлена OS Windows.
В VirtualBox в качестве настроек сети выбран "Сетевой мост".
Как мне это все заставить работать. Я не вижу пакеты в OS Windows.
Подскажите куда смотреть или что мне необходимо настроить?

Запустил акулу внутри виртуалки и на одном из интерфейсов обнаружил свои пакеты

```
Interface name: br-2a43a1957f87
```

Попробовал такой вариант

```
services:    
  upload-srv:
    image: ${SERV_IMAGE_STEND}
    networks:
      - es-serv-network
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: es-serv-v01
    volumes:
      - /home/es-serv:/home/es-serv
    ports:
      - "5003:5003"
  upload-web:
    image: ${WEB_IMAGE}
    networks:
      - es-serv-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: es-serv-web-v01
    ports:
      - "7001:80"
...        
networks:
  es-serv-network:
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to add interface veth5893d6c to sandbox: error setting interface "veth5893d6c" IP to 172.19.0.2/16: cannot program address 172.19.0.2/16 in sandbox interface because it conflicts with existing route {Ifindex: 21 Dst: 172.19.0.0/16 Src: 172.19.0.1 Gw: <nil> Flags: [] Table: 254}
```

Может быть эта ошибка возникает из-за того, что в у меня в docker-compose присутствует веб-контейнер.
Вот что выдает команда

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                              DRIVER    SCOPE
5634bc38b59b   bridge                            bridge    local
5c982c6631dc   host                              host      local
5a0bcc32d0bd   es-serv_es-serv-network   bridge    local
bfe4ffa4fa33   none                              null      local
e0cc8c05cc7e   upload_upload-network             bridge    local
```

Это случайно не тот самый host о который я пробую добавить с помощью

```
network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multicast не форвардится роутерами и прокси к нему не запустить.

Вывести это приложение в "мир" можно. Для этого вместо проброса портов разрешите ему общаться с сетевушкой. Документация https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

```
network_mode: host
```

Я если приложению нужен отдельный адрес, то я обычно запускаю через `macvlan`. А что-то простенькое в режиме `host`

Comment: У меня при запуске выдает ошибку. Я добавил код в вопрос

Comment: networks убирай

Comment: Удалил networks из этого контейнера, теперь я вижу свои посылки на хосте. Вот только почему-то на другом физическом хосте, где у меня стоит приложения для их чтения их не обнаруживаю

Comment: Наверное это тема для другого вопроса

Comment: @alexmntmnk а теперь надо виртуалбокс прокинуть) сеть настроить в режим моста(bridge) или macvlan

Comment: Так у меня на виртуалке на Адптере1 выбран тип Сетевой мост. Дело в том, что пакеты теперь приходят на физический хост. Я их там вижу, проблема в том, что я не вижу их на другом физическом хосте, где у меня запущена программа для чтения этих пакетов, но не вижу я их даже акулой ни на одном из интерфейсов.

Comment: проверь этот мост ttl не уменьшает ли

Comment: подскажите, а несколько сетей в режиме macvlan возможно запустить?

Comment: а зачем? можно, но в этом врятли есть смысл

Comment: да просто я не знаю как по другому передать мультикаст из виртуалки в разные сетевые интерфейсы на хосте. В идеале хотелось бы из одного приложения осуществлять такую передачу. Но тут уже рассматриваю вариант из двух его копий и кажадая из которых будет работать со своей сетью macvlan. Может есть более правильно решение. Но я его не знаю

Comment: наверное правильным решением было бы `igmpproxy` и обычная сеть...

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду? Настроить igmpproxy в коммутаторе? Но у меня же задача отправить данные по нескольким сетевым интерфейсам хоста из виртуалки. При этом сетевой интерфейс это имеется ввиду физический порт в сетевой плате, можно сказать, что отдельная сетевая плата на хосте. Т.е. мне надо раскидать эти потоки до коммутатора

Comment: в линукс машине

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136762/discussion-between-alexmntmnk-and-eri).

Comment: где-то можно почитать как это делается. Есть доступное описание, просто я не админ, а разработчик и такими вещами ни когда не занимался

Comment: тут ещё вопрос что за приложение... мультикаст 2х стороний или iptv?

Comment: это не iptv а самописное приложение на java отправляющее пакеты всего лишь на одну другую машину. Почему мультикаст, не спрашивайте, кому-то захотелось.  По сути я просто делаю имитацию железки, которой у нас нет, для проверки работы нашей системы. И эта железка на выходе имеет 4 ETH порта в которые плюет эти данные. 
Пока что обмен односторонний. Но придется делать имитацию еще одной железки и там уже он будет 2-х сторонний.

Comment: в таком случае macvlan самое то... а зачем вам 2 порта?

Comment: не понял о каких портах идет речь? Если об ETH , то сама железка имеет 4 сетевых выхода, а мне надо ее полностью повторить

Comment: так они на свиче скорее всего. считай пятипортовый свич за 300рублей подключить к сетевушке... или у железки несколько мак?

Comment: я предлагал вариант со свичем, но не хотят, типа не совсем полная иммитация. Хотя я особой разницы не вижу. Да, железка имеет 4 мака

Comment: если 4 порта объеденены в мост, то сделай мост. если нет, то я бы в режиме host сделал

Comment: про режим хост я не понял. Что мне это даст? Как траффик при этом разойдется по 4-м сетевым инерфейсам?

Comment: это уже приложение будет решать как оно разойдется.

Comment: а режим хост просто снимет всю не нужную изоляцию

Comment: Вот только проблематично такое на java реализовать. Я даже не знаю как из приложения java можно достучаться до нужного интерфейса.

Comment: Железка то как-то выбирает -  уточните как и вопрос будет решён.